# Is $x$ in a field $(A,+,*)$such that ${\forall}y\,{\in}\,A:x*y=0$ unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(A,+,*)$ be a field. Let $0$ be the ring zero. Is there any $x\,{\in}\,A:{\forall}y\,{\in}\,A:x*y=0$ such that $x$ is not $0$?

Comment: If $y\neq 0$ is such an element, then multiplying the expression $xy=0$ by $y^{-1}$ gives $x=0$.

Answer (score 4):

A non-zero element is invertible. Multiply both sides by inverse.